react: The method inside the function component cannot obtain the latest value of the useState variable
I have the following code:
import { useState, useEffect } from "preact/hooks";

export function App() {
    const [pageContent, setPageContent] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        setPageContent("main");

        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(222, pageContent); // main
    }, [pageContent]);

    const handleScroll = () => {
        console.log(333, pageContent); // ""
    };

    retrun (
        <>
            <p>enough content to make the page scroll</p>
        </>
    )
}


I expected that at line 17 of the code, which is the location of console.log(333), pageContent should be "main", but it is the initialized value "".
I'm confused, can anyone tell me why and how to get the expected "main"?

read on stale closures; It has value from the initial render.

Thank you for pointing out the reason. I also found the solution myself, using useRef to replace useState.

Why initialise pageContent to "" if you want to immediately set it to "main" anyway?

You have a few major mistakes here:

Don't create callback function that only be used in useEffect outside of useEffect
Your useEffect needs the value of pageContent, so it must have pageContent as a dependency
If the pageContent is not supposed to change somewhere else in the component, don't use useState, don't use useRef either, use a simple variable. I.e: const pageContent = 'main'. This will also apply if the value of pageContent is derived from other values.
Use must unsubscribe any event listener in the return of useEffect

This is the demonstration of every points above:
export function App() {
    const [pageContent, setPageContent] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        setPageContent("main");

        const handleScroll = () => {
            console.log(333, pageContent);
        };    
        const unsubscribe = window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

        return unsubscribe;
    }, [pageContent]);
 
    retrun (
        <>
            <p>enough content to make the page scroll</p>
        </>
    )
}


.addEventListener does not have a return value. "Don't create callback function that only be used in useEffect outside of useEffect" why? It should be a memoized callback with useCallbackso it definitely can be defined outside of useEffect. "If the pageContent is not supposed to change somewhere else...use a simple variable" no, function components have to be pure. "Use must unsubscribe any event listener in the return of useEffect" that is correct, too bad you dont show it in your answer.

The code in this answer reads like it was written by AI, so please remember that AI-generated content is banned on Stack Overflow.


Because you'll need to put the function inside the dependency array; otherwise, you'll get a lint warning. And if you do put it in the dependency array, you'll need a useCallback to wrap round that function, which can be all avoided if you define the function inside the useEffect

